# getting a 2d array in perl from input

Tags: perl

I want to get a 2d array from input in Perl.
I will get 2 inputs for number of rows and column of the matrix and get the input in 2 for loops

First I get two variables named $row and $column from input.

Now what I used to do in python was I made 2 for loops and input like this:

```
matrix = []
for i in range (row):
    temp = []
    for j in range (column):
        x <- input()
        temp.append(x)
    matrix.append(temp)
```

And now in matrix I have the matrix user has inputted.

In Perl though I can't do the same thing.

this is my code:

```
print("enter number of rows: ");
chomp(my $row = <>);
print("enter number of columns: ");
chomp(my $column = <>);
my @matrix = ();
for (my $r=0; $r<$row; $r=$r+1){
    my @list = [];
    for(my $c=0; $c<$column; $c=$c+1){
        print("input:\n");
        chomp(my $input = <>);
        push(@list, $input);
    }
    print("list now @list\n");
    push(@matrix, @list);
}

print("final matrix @matrix\n");
print("$matrix[0][0]\n");
```

This is the output I get after the line print("final matrix @matrix\n"); executes:

```
final matrix ARRAY(0xddb038) 1 2 ARRAY(0xddb068) 3 4
and after the last print i get this:
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at test.pl line 94, <> line 6.
```

(btw line 6 is a comment)
this is the whole input and output:

```
enter number of rows: 2
enter number of columns: 2
input:
1
input:
2
list now ARRAY(0xddb038) 1 2
input:
3
input:
4
list now ARRAY(0xddb068) 3 4
final matrix ARRAY(0xddb038) 1 2 ARRAY(0xddb068) 3 4
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at test.pl line 94, <> line 6.
```

So basically I want the user to input 2 numbers (n and m) and then input an n*m matrix. I can get the 2 numbers. but when getting the numbers of the matrix, I am doing something wrong in pushing it (appending it) to the main matrix and I think I have not understood the difference of '$' and '@' and also [] and ().

Comment: Can you tell what should be the expected output?

Comment: i get $row and $column as input. and now in two for loops i want to input a matrix (2d array) of size $rwo*$column. i tried using the same approach as i do in python (gave a pseudo code of it). now here in Perl i can not do the same thing.

Comment: Start by reading https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut and https://perldoc.perl.org/perllol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're mixing two different approaches.

Working with an array:

```perl
my @list;                    # Create an array.
push( @list, $input );       # Add to it.
push( @matrix, \@list );     # Add a reference to it to @matrix.
```

Working with a reference to an array:

```perl
my $list = [];               # Create an anonymous array
push( @$list, $input );      # Add to it.
push( @matrix, $list );      # Add a reference to it to @matrix.
```

Note that `[]` returns a reference to the anonymous array it creates, so we store that in a scalar. It also means we need to dereference that scalar to access the array (as see in the middle `push` of the second snippet).

Note that arrays can't contain arrays, so we approximate arrays of arrays with arrays of array references. (Like Python, really.) So we need to create a reference (e.g. using `\`) if we have a named array. (This is the part that's different than Python, since you always have a reference there.)

I prefer the first approach, but either is fine.

---

Tip:

Arrays already start empty.

```perl
my @matrix = ();
```

is better written as

```perl
my @matrix;
```

---

Tip:

C-style for loops are extremely dense, hard to read.

```perl
for (my $r=0; $r<$row; $r=$r+1)
```

is better written as

```perl
for my $r ( 0 .. $r-1 )
```

Comment: Made some big changes to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to `push`. You can assign the value to the matrix's respective row and column (`$matrix[$i][$j] = $val;`).

See the below script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict; use warnings;

print "Enter the number of rows:";
my $rows = <STDIN>;
chomp $rows;

print "Enter the number of columns:";
my $cols = <STDIN>;
chomp $cols;

my @matrix;

for (my $i=0; $i< $rows; $i++){
    for (my $j = 0; $j < $cols; $j++){
        print "Enter value for row $i and column $j:";
        chomp (my $val = <STDIN>);
        $matrix[$i][$j] = $val;
    }
}

print "Matrix:\n";
for (my $i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++){
    for  (my $j = 0; $j < $cols; $j++){
        print "$matrix[$i][$j]\t";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Result:

```
Enter the number of rows:2
Enter the number of columns:2
Enter value for row 0 and column 0:4
Enter value for row 0 and column 1:3
Enter value for row 1 and column 0:2
Enter value for row 1 and column 1:1

Matrix:
4   3   
2   1
```

Comment: well this is a lot easier than working with references. thanks for the answer I would never have thought this to be possible in Perl.